# Align issue: Either missing } or paragraph ended before \align complete. Help?

Tags: align

```
Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m$ be independent standard normal random variables. Then \\
\begin{align}
\textbf{E}(X_{1}^2+X_{2}^2+\ldots+X_{m}^2)^n 
    &= \sum_{substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}\textbf{E}X_{1}^{2i_1}\ldots\textbf{E}X_{m}^{2i_m}\\
    &= \sum_{substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}(2i_{1}-1)!!\ldots(2i_{m}-1)!!\\
    &= \sum_{substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\frac{n!\times2^{i_1}i_{1}!(2i_{1}-1)!!\ldots2^{i_m}i_{m}!(2i_{m}-1)!!}{2^{n}(i_{1}!)^2\ldots(i_{m}!)^2}\\
    &= \sum_{substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\frac{n!}{2^n}\binom{2i_1}{i_1}\ldots\binom{2i_m}{i_m}.
\end{align}
```

Comment: You are missing `\ ` before `substack`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's better to post examples that others can use directly (for error checking instead of fragments)

Comment: Thank you, sir! I hadn't even noticed that wasn't there. I was having some alignment troubles before, and got it to work. After inserting the substack, it happened again. Hadn't even considered the fact \ was missing

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `\` before `\substack` but please always post complete documents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}



Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m$ be independent standard normal random variables. Then \\
\begin{align}
\textbf{E}(X_{1}^2+X_{2}^2+\ldots+X_{m}^2)^n 
    &= \sum_{\substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}\textbf{E}X_{1}^{2i_1}\ldots\textbf{E}X_{m}^{2i_m}\\
    &= \sum_{\substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\binom{n}{i_1,\ldots,i_m}(2i_{1}-1)!!\ldots(2i_{m}-1)!!\\
    &= \sum_{\substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\frac{n!\times2^{i_1}i_{1}!(2i_{1}-1)!!\ldots2^{i_m}i_{m}!(2i_{m}-1)!!}{2^{n}(i_{1}!)^2\ldots(i_{m}!)^2}\\
    &= \sum_{\substack{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_m\geq0\\i_1+\ldots+i_m=n}}\frac{n!}{2^n}\binom{2i_1}{i_1}\ldots\binom{2i_m}{i_m}.
\end{align}



\end{document}
```

The above is without error but is rather too wide, it fits better if you use
`\textbf{E}(X_{1}^2+\ldots+X_{m}^2)^n` losing the `X_2` term.